# How to loop htmlspecialchars on array in array in array in

Tags: php, xss

I'm creating a function that "cleans" data (escapes html to avoid xss) from the database before sending it to the views. All the data is passed on in 1 array. This arrays contains variables and arrays that contain other variables and arrays, and so on.

This is what I have now, it works, but it just doesn't look right. Is there any way to avoid going through a new foreach for every array inside an array?

```
public function clean_output(&$data)
{
  if(!is_array($data))
  {
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  }
  else
  {
    foreach($data as &$data_1)
    {
      if(!is_array($data_1))
      {
        $data_1 = htmlspecialchars($data_1);
      }
      else
      {
        foreach($data_1 as &$data_2)
        {
          if(!is_array($data_2))
          {
            $data_2 = htmlspecialchars($data_2);
          }
          else
          {
            foreach($data_2 as &$data_3)
            {
              $data_3 = htmlspecialchars($data_3);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to Antoine, I got a new function. Suggestions still welcome offcourse!

```
public function clean_output(&$data)
    {
      if(!is_array($data))
      {
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      }
      else
      {
        foreach($data as &$data_1)
        {
          $this->clean_output($data_1);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use recursive function !
http://www.elated.com/articles/php-recursive-functions/